# How to customize an HTTPError via pytest and raise it while testing phase to see whether a method could handle it?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I use pytest and try to raise an exception at testing phase to test whether the exception could be handled by the method. But seems it always pass, even I delete the try...except... block.

This is the class which has an error and has been handled

```
class SaltConfig(GridLayout):
    def check_phone_number_on_first_contact(self, button):
        s = self.instanciate_ServerMsg(tt)

        try:
            s.send()
        except HTTPError as err:
            print("[HTTPError] : " + str(err.code))
            return

        # some code when running without error

    def instanciate_ServerMsg():
        return ServerMsg()
```

This is the helper class which generates the ServerMsg object used by the former class.

```
class ServerMsg(OrderedDict):
    def send(self,answerCallback=None):
        #send something to server via urllib.urlopen
```

This is my tests code:

```
class TestSaltConfig:
    def test_check_phone_number_on_first_contact(self):
        myError = HTTPError(url="http://127.0.0.1", code=500,
                            msg="HTTP Error Occurs", hdrs="donotknow", fp=None)

        mockServerMsg = mock.Mock(spec=ServerMsg)
        mockServerMsg.send.side_effect = myError

        mockSalt = mock.Mock(spec=SaltConfig)
        mockSalt.instanciate_ServerMsg.return_value = mockServerMsg

        mockSalt.check_phone_number_on_first_contact(self, "2")
```

I think the above code doesn't make much sense since I'm actually testing on a mockObject, but the reason is that I don't know how to raise an exception when calling a method when the exception is already handled.

How to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using `decorator` instead of `Mock library` to achieve your purpose.

I slightly modified your code to make it runnable in my environment.

```
import unittest

def exception_function(f, exception_type):
    def exception_fn(*args, **kwargs):
        raise exception_type
    def fn(*args, **kwargs):
        return exception_fn
    return fn

def wrap(f, exception_type):
    @exception_function(f, exception_type)
    def fn(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return fn

class ServerMsg():
    def send(self):
        print("send normally")

class SaltConfig():
    def check_phone_number_on_first_contact(self):
        s = ServerMsg()
        try:
            s.send()
        except ValueError:
            print("raise exception")

class TestSaltConfig(unittest.TestCase):   
    def test_check_phone_number_on_first_contact(self):
        s = SaltConfig()

        original_method = ServerMsg.send
        print (ServerMsg.send) #<unbound method ServerMsg.send>

        s.check_phone_number_on_first_contact() #send normally

        ServerMsg.send = wrap(ServerMsg.send, ValueError)
        print (ServerMsg.send) #<unbound method ServerMsg.exception_fn>

        s.check_phone_number_on_first_contact() #raise exception

        ServerMsg.send = original_method
        print (ServerMsg.send) #<unbound method ServerMsg.send>
```